# how to show the page header value in downloaded pdf from intractive report

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a interactive report with some values and in that page header I have some tiles and dates. When I click the download and open the interactive report PDF file,
I want the page headers to be added in the PDF eg: titles and dates 
which is in page header should be added in PDF

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have printing needs that go beyond what APEX does out of the box. There are many options for this, I'll mention two.

Many folks in the APEX community are loving APEX Office Print (AOP): 
https://www.apexofficeprint.com/index.html

Another option is PL/PDF:
https://www.plpdf.com/